# How to remove certain xticks or yticks in a a matplotlib subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting multiple plots using subplot.

[image]

I would like to remove all yticks except for those on the left, and all xticks except for those on the bottom. I am trying to create shared axes.

I have tried some stackoverflow answers such as using `plt.tick_params` and targeting certain subplots:

```
    if num in [2,3,5,6,8,9] :
        plt.tick_params(labelleft='off')
    if num not in range(7) :
        plt.tick_params(labelbottom='off')
```

I have also tried adjusting `tick_params` at the very end:

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', right=False, left=True, top=False, bottom=True)
```

However all yticks and xticks appear every time.

Is there another method I can try?

My plotting code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


sns.set_style("whitegrid")
myl = sns.color_palette().as_hex()

num=0

# figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 30))


for column in newtempgraph.drop(['local_date'], axis=1):

    num+=1

    # Find the right spot on the plot
    plt.subplot(7,3, num)

    # Plot the lineplot
    plt.plot(newtempgraph['local_date'], newtempgraph[column],  color=myl[num-1], linewidth=1.9, alpha=0.9, label=column,linestyle='--')

    # Same limits for everybody
    plt.xlim(newtempgraph['local_date'].min(),newtempgraph['local_date'].max())
    plt.ylim(0,1464)

    # Not ticks everywhere
    if num in [2,3,5,6,8,9] :
        plt.tick_params(labelleft='off')
    if num not in range(7) :
        plt.tick_params(labelbottom='off')

    # Add title
    plt.title(column, loc='left', fontsize=20, fontweight=0, color=myl[num-1] )
    plt.xticks(fontsize=13,rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=15)

plt.suptitle("Performance of Shops", fontsize=20, fontweight=0, color='black', style='italic', y=1.02)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', right=False, left=True, top=False, bottom=True)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', right=False, left=True, top=False, bottom=True)
```

And my df, for using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`:

```
{'local_date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-06 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-13 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-20 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-02-03 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-02-10 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-02-17 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-02-24 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-03-02 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-03-09 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2020-03-23 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2020-03-30 00:00:00')},
 'shop1': {0: 100.0,
  1: 156.0,
  2: 1231.0,
  3: 360.0,
  4: 250.0,
  5: 150.0,
  6: 1287.0,
  7: 397.0,
  8: 546.0,
  9: 270.0,
  10: 50.0,
  11: 1464.0,
  12: 280.0},
 'shop2': {0: 0.0,
  1: 430.0,
  2: 270.0,
  3: 900.0,
  4: 665.0,
  5: 750.0,
  6: 780.0,
  7: 360.0,
  8: 704.0,
  9: 480.0,
  10: 470.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 730.0},
 'shop3': {0: 222.0,
  1: 258.0,
  2: 255.0,
  3: 367.0,
  4: 332.0,
  5: 324.0,
  6: 269.0,
  7: 336.0,
  8: 492.0,
  9: 349.0,
  10: 329.0,
  11: 354.0,
  12: 581.0},
 'shop4': {0: 607.0,
  1: 140.0,
  2: 172.0,
  3: 89.0,
  4: 63.0,
  5: 700.0,
  6: 157.0,
  7: 401.0,
  8: 112.0,
  9: 180.0,
  10: 76.0,
  11: 104.0,
  12: 346.0},
 'shop5': {0: 51.0,
  1: 375.0,
  2: 78.0,
  3: 92.0,
  4: 59.0,
  5: 193.0,
  6: 137.0,
  7: 96.0,
  8: 331.0,
  9: 195.0,
  10: 291.0,
  11: 347.0,
  12: 190.0},
 'shop6': {0: 150.0,
  1: 225.0,
  2: 345.0,
  3: 150.0,
  4: 230.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 500.0,
  7: 150.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 230.0,
  10: 50.0,
  11: 270.0,
  12: 0.0},
 'shop7': {0: 39.0,
  1: 130.0,
  2: 278.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 585.0,
  6: 175.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 360.0,
  9: 79.0,
  10: 135.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0},
 'shop8': {0: 74.0,
  1: 66.0,
  2: 75.0,
  3: 95.0,
  4: 158.0,
  5: 50.0,
  6: 233.0,
  7: 117.0,
  8: 146.0,
  9: 142.0,
  10: 261.0,
  11: 30.0,
  12: 85.0},
 'shop9': {0: 74.0,
  1: 146.0,
  2: 166.0,
  3: 6.0,
  4: 75.0,
  5: 22.0,
  6: 33.0,
  7: 18.0,
  8: 15.0,
  9: 110.0,
  10: 150.0,
  11: 144.0,
  12: 561.0}}
```

Comment: `labelleft` and `labelbottom` need to be Boolean, so `plt.tick_params(labelleft=False)` in your loop should work

Comment: I must have been following an outdated tutorial with the 'off' method. Yours boolean works, thanks. You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params.html) documentation shows that `labelleft` and `labelbottom` need to be Boolean.

Therefore, change:

```
plt.tick_params(labelleft='off')
```

to

```
plt.tick_params(labelleft=False)
```